# Printing Table with empty field

Tags: pdftex

I am working with Python and have an array of numbers. For example:

```
    a = (1,2,3,4,5,6)
    b = (1,3,5)
    c = (2,4,6)
```

Now I want to print these array in Latex Table as below format:

```
a   c   b
1       1
2   2  
3       3
4   4
5       5
6   6
```

I dont know how to print the void places. Any help?

Comment: Please clearify what you want to achieve here. Is it a mathematical or programming language array or shall it be displayed as table?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, i have edited the question. thanks for asking. yap, I have got the arrays from Python program which I want to publish in Latex.

Comment: I like Monty Python, but I've no idea of Python as a language, but isn't `PythonTeX` designed for this?

Comment: Are your arrays always sorted?  Is the first array always a "superarray" of the others?  There are repeated numbers within each array?  If there are repeated numbers, how do you plan to align them?  Anyway, these seems a programming problem (sequence alignment), not a LaTeX question.  I would solve it within Python.  You can align sorted arrays in linear time.